# Rremote setup of cygwin's sshd

Tags: windows, cygwin, sshd, psexec

OK.. This is a catch 22.. you want to get cygwin's ssh server up and running so that you can get remote access to a machine.. In my case, lots of machines.  However, now you have to remote install something to give you remote acess.  I have already used psexec to give me what I want in the way of installing ssh.  The problems comes when I want to use psexec to login to cygwin and setup the sshd and install it as a service as while running psexec I am using the SYSTEM account which cygwin tells me has some permission errors.
Any one have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser site! OK, since psexec can't authenticate into an SSH daemon, I'm guessing you're using psexec to launch a SSH client, like Putty, to get you SSH'd into your Cygwin SSH daemon - right? Also please tell us the permission errors you're getting. Either edit your question to add the errors, or add them as a comment.

Comment: I am runnin psexec to get my cygwin ssh daemon up and running so that I can use an ssh client to log into my machine instead of using psexec.

Comment: I keep re-reading your post and your comment, and still can't understand what you're trying to do. Could you please take another crack at explaining exactly what you are trying to do? I'm quite familiar with all the technologies but need a clear description. Thanks in advance. :)